# How to fix AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'itemsize'

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5],index=[5,4,3,2,1])
print(s.itemsize)


return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
```

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'itemsize'
i updated pandas with latest version after same error occuring that series object has no itemsize attribute

Comment: The [docs page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.3/reference/api/pandas.Series.itemsize.html) says "Deprecated since version 0.23.0." Seems like you didn't do yourself any favors updating to the latest version

Answer (score 1):

Itemsize attribute is used to return the size of elements in a series. However, in newer versions, they have removed the Itemsize as it is of no use any longer. It is because for most of the values (maybe, all), the size is always 8 bytes, and using it would return 8 every time.

But if you still want to check how it works, you can use the syntax given below:

`print(s.values.itemsize)`

In this way you can get the size of each element in the output (which should be, as usual, *8* (8 bytes)).